# Gradient color for kdeplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, kdeplot

I'm looking to plot a gradient of color that represents the density in seaborn 0.12.x
Before it seems that the argument cmap was accepted : [Add labels to Seaborn bivariate KDE plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991657/add-labels-to-seaborn-bivariate-kde-plot)
It seems to not be the case in the 0.12.x https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html and I don't manage to create a similar graph in 0.12.x
Here is a quick example :

```
a = np.random.random((1000,))
b = np.random.random((1000,))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
ax = sns.kdeplot(x='A', y='B',
                 # cmap="Greens",
                 data=df)
plt.show()
```

Note that I don't want to have filling, I'm really looking to have only lines.

Comment: `ax = sns.kdeplot(x='A', y='B', color="green", data=df)`

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3058) introduced in 0.12.0; there is [a fix](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/3065) in the master branch and it will be released with 0.12.1 in the next week or so.